# macro run-time error '9': subscript out of range with macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro with VBA. If you push a button in excel it will excecute a code. Below is the first part of the code. If I excecute the program then i get the runtime error 9, subscript out of range. How can I solve this error? The error points to  `ReDim rij(1 To z) As Integer`

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("InvoerIO").Range("O1") = z

ReDim rij(1 To z) As Integer  

For r = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("InvoerIO").Range("O1")         
    If r > 7 Then
        z = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("InvoerIO").Range("O1")
        rij(r) = rij(r - 1)    
        If Sheets("InvoerIO").Cells(r, 3).value = "part1" Then        
            rij(r) = 90
```

etc.

Comment: What value does `z` take?

Comment: z was an Integer

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("InvoerIO").Range("O1") = z
```

to

```
z = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("InvoerIO").Range("O1").Value
```